# How to fix the " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' " in my code

Tags: python, sockets

I am actually implementing a classic multiplayer game using python curses library. I have made a `snake.py` file which is the client and a `server.py` file for this purpose. I have tried looking at the data and making sure I am parsing the received data correctly and sending it correctly to make sure I am not sending an empty string but still on the `snake.py` the position that my server sends in the start is an empty string which the function parse cannot convert since `int()` cannot convert an empty string.

Here is a link to my code where you should only open server_multi.py and server.py.

https://github.com/hamza24farrukh/Netcen-cs-382/tree/master/assignment2/snake%20IO

and here are the two links to the pictures of both of my terminals
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JRL9.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnNLw.jpg

The main question is how do i fix my code so that it starts sending and receiving data between two clients which is when i open two instances of my snake_multi.py file. I have already implemented threading and my server is somehow sending bizarre data while my client is unable to parse it. Please point out where i am making a mistake in my implementation.

Comment: Please post your code **and** error messages as text, not image.

Comment: @Selcuk i have posted my code on github and added the link here. my code is in snake_multi.py file and server.py file there. The error message is in the title. But i am facing problem in sending and receiving data from a client and then sending it to another client. I have implemented threading which makes a new thread for each client but i dont know why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>int('33')
33
>>>int('33.44')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '33.44'
```

So, python recognises an integer string, but it raises a `ValueError` if it get an invalid string or a float value.

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So, this is the error in your code. Check for this.
You can also use

```
try:
   int('') #or your code
except ValueError:
   pass      # or whatever
```

Comment: i did this but now another error is File "snake_multi.py", line 26, in parse_data      │
│                                                                            data = s.recv(1024)                                                               │
│               ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Comment: i have implemented threading in my code but i am somehow not able to send and receive data between two clients.

Comment: You can create a new question here, and send the full error message with the broken code. People will help more quickly if you are specific on what you want.